# How to make a php file to load in a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my js

```
function load_date_cong(id,date)
    {
    //alert(date);
    $("#date0").removeClass('selected');
    $("#date1").removeClass('selected');
    $("#date2").removeClass('selected');
    $("#date3").removeClass('selected');
    $("#date4").removeClass('selected');
    $("#date5").removeClass('selected');
    $("#date6").removeClass('selected');
    $("#date7").removeClass('selected');                
    //$("#"+date).toggleClass('selected');  

    $("#"+id).addClass('selected');

    $('#date_conf_field').html("<center><img src='images/loader.gif' /></center>");
    $.get("conf_list.php",{date:date},function(msg){$('#date_conf_field').html(msg);});
    }
```

This is the code

February 2014

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="2014-03"  id="date1" onclick="load_date_cong(this.id, this.name);">March 2014</a></li>


<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="2014-04"  id="date2" onclick="load_date_cong(this.id, this.name);">April 2014</a></li>


<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="2014-05"  id="date3" onclick="load_date_cong(this.id, this.name);">May 2014</a></li>


<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="2014-06"  id="date4" onclick="load_date_cong(this.id, this.name);">June 2014</a></li>


<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="2014-07"  id="date5" onclick="load_date_cong(this.id, this.name);">July 2014</a></li>


<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="2014-08"  id="date6" onclick="load_date_cong(this.id, this.name);">August 2014</a></li>
```

How to make the php file ?

Comment: When do you want to load the php rendered data? At page load or after a JS event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use load() function https://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#divID").load("your.php")
```

Comment: Don't forget the OP was passing data as well. Should be `$('#date_conf_field').load('conf_list.php', { date: date });`...

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery "load". Much cleaner/easier!

```
$('#date_conf_field').load("conf_list.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

If  the rest of the page is served by php you can do this:

```
<div>
<?php include "conf_list.php";?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could really clean this up and simplify things. You've got a few things I wouldn't recommend:

- Obtrusive JavaScript
- Deprecated tag usage `<center>`
- Multiple `onclick=""` handlers

Now to the cleanup:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-date="2014-03" id="date1" >March 2014</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-date="2014-04" id="date2" >April 2014</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-date="2014-05" id="date3" >May 2014</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-date="2014-06" id="date4" >June 2014</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-date="2014-07" id="date5">July 2014</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-date="2014-08" id="date6">August 2014</a></li>
</ul>
```

*Changes:*

1. Remove the obtrusive *JavaScript* from your markup.
2. Change the name attribute to use the new `data-*` *HTML5* attributes.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('ul').off('click', 'li > a').on('click', 'li > a', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $('a[id^="date"]').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        $('<img />', { "src": "images/loader.gif" }).appendTo('#date_conf_field');
        $('#date_conf_field').load("conf_list.php", { date: $this.data('date') });
    });
});
```

*Changes:*

1. Prevent the anchor tag from redirecting using `event.preventDefault();`.
2. Save a reference of the clicked element off into a variable `$(this)` to prevent re-traversing the DOM.
3. Add a delegated event handler to the unordered list so that only ***one*** click event need be applied.
4. Remove all the jQuery selectors that are removing the class `selected` and replace them with a `starts with` attribute selector.
5. By building the `<img>` with the `$('<img />'...)` syntax, you're allowing jQuery to use the native `document.createElement` internally.
6. Finally, use [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the HTML template and place it in your element.
7. Pull your date data from the clicked element using the jQuery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

**CSS:**

```
img[src~="load"] {
    text-align: center;
}
```

*Changes:*

1. Remove the deprecated `<center>` tag from your image markup.
2. Target your loading image with the `contains` attribute selector.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/E5j7L/4/)

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? The OP has a lot of things he/she could optimize in their code. There's nothing wrong with this answer...